# Azure Logic App - Assign variable to another variable results in a different value. Possible bug?

Tags: azure

I created a simple Azure Logic App that loops through every row in an excel table and assigns the value of a field in the file called "Input ID" to a variable called "Input ID" and then assigns the value of Input ID to another variable called "Message to User"; however, the values of "Input ID" and "Message to User" are different. Could someone help explain what I may be doing wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXnxW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pakj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour of Foreach [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#change-for-each-concurrency) is to execute all steps concurrently or in parallel which would possibly explain why you are seeing the different values.

If you want to change this behaviour to execute each step only after the previous one has finished(i.e. sequentially), you can do this following the instructions [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#run-for-each-loops-sequentially).